# How can I put the <br> tag in a long string after every 5 words?

Tags: javascript

Example:

```
let str = "Hello this is a test string to figure out how is it possible to split a long string into multiple string";
```

I want to put the `<br>` tag after every 5 words like so:

```
let str1 = "Hello this is a test<br>string to figure out how<br>is it possible to split<br>a long string into multiple<br>string";
```

How can I do this?

Comment: good question! I have searched through stackoverflow and didn't find good answer to such question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a bunch of working answers with different approaches but none that uses RegExp so here I'll contribute with one that does:

```
str1 = str.match(/([^ ]+ +){5}|.+/g).join('<br>');
```

`([^ ]+ +)` matches non-spaces (i.e. words) followed by spaces. `{5}` means it has to match this five times in a row, giving us the match of five words with spaces in between. `|.+` is to include anything that remains of the string after the last five word match. The `g` flag is needed because without it, it would only match a single occurrence. The matches end up in an array, which we `join()` with `'<br>'`.

Answer (score 5):

You can `split` the string on spaces, `map` the elements of resulting `Array` to either words preceded by space or every 6th word by `<br>` and `join` the result back to a `String`. Something like:

```js
const str2Split = "Hello this is a test string to figure out how is it possible to split a long string into multiple string";

const withAddedBreaks = str2Split.split(" ") 
  .map( (v, i) => `${i && i % 5 == 0 ? "<br>" : " "}${v}`);
//                   ^ insert <br> after every 5 words, otherwise a space
console.log(withAddedBreaks.join("").trim());
//                                   ^ remove first space

console.log(`use method: replace every 4rd space with " !#! "\n${
  replaceEveryNthSpace(str2Split, 3, " !#! ")}`);

// a method for it
function replaceEveryNthSpace(str, n, substr) {
  return str
  .split(" ") 
  .map( (v, i) => `${i && i % n == 0 ? substr : " "}${v}`)
  .join("")
  .trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
str
 .split(' ')
 .reduce((accumulator, word, index) =>
   accumulator + word + (index !== 0 && index % 5 === 0 ? '<br>' : ' ')
 , '');
```

So what happens here is we split the string into an array of words using the space character. Then we iterate over the array using `Array.prototype.reduce` and add each word back on to an accumulator string along with a space, or a `<br>` tag if it the array index is a multiple of 5.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```js
    let defaultStr = "Hello this is a test string to figure out how is it possible to split a long string into multiple string";
    let field = document.getElementById('string');

    window.onload = function() {
        field.innerHTML = defaultStr;
    };

    function addBr(){
        const arrayWords = defaultStr.split(' ');
        let str = '';
        let numAddBr = 5;

        arrayWords.forEach((value, numberWord) => {
            numberWord++;
            if(numberWord % numAddBr === 0) str+= '<br>'
            str+= `${value} `;
        })

        field.innerHTML = str
    }
```

```html
    <div id="string"></div>
    <button onclick="addBr()">add Br</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "Hello this is a test string to figure out how is it possible to split a long string into multiple string";
var new_str="";
str.split(" ").forEach(function (val,i){new_str += val+((i+1)%5==0?"<br>":" ");});

console.log(new_str);
document.write(new_str);
```

> What if multiple spaces are present between two words?

Use this function:

```js
function addtext(str,gap_len,texttoaddbetweenstr){
    var new_str="";
    str=str.replace(/ {1,}/g," ");
    str.split(" ").forEach(function (val,i){new_str += val+((i+1)%gap_len== 0 ? texttoaddbetweenstr:" ");});
    return new_str;
}

var str1 = "Hello this is a test string to figure out how is it possible to split a long string into multiple string";
var str_with_multiple_spaces = "Hello   this is  a test string to figure out how is        it possible   to split   a long string    into multiple string";
console.log(addtext(str1,5,"<br>"));
console.log(addtext(str_with_multiple_spaces,5,"<br>"));
console.log(addtext(str1,1,"|"));
console.log("To remove spaces: "+addtext(str1,1,""));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `filter` with initial result like the first element is final result and the last is the index of the current word, every 5 word, we put the `<br>` to the final array word and recalculate the current index, the last step is join the word array and replace the unnecessary empty string like this:

```js
let str = "Hello this is a test string to figure out how is it possible to split a long string into multiple string";

let result = str.split(" ").reduce((rs, el) => 
  { 
    
    if (rs[1] == 5) { 
      rs[0].push("<br>")
      rs[1] = 0
    }
    else {

      rs[0].push(el)
      rs[1]++;
    }
    return rs;
   }
  ,[[], 0]
)[0].join(" ").replace(/ <br>/g, "<br>");
console.log(result);
```